# Nested searches Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

I'm using geocoder to search for events. I want to allow for more detailed searches. Currently my 'events' have a location, time, and with have a few selectors. I would like the user to be able to search on all of these parameters (any set at a time).

eventController

```
  def index
if params[:search].present?
  @events = Event.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance)
else
  @events = Event.all
end
@user = current_user
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @events }
end
```

end

current Index.html.erb

```
<h1>Events</h1>

<%= form_tag events_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= text_field_tag :timeMin, params[:timeMin] %>
    <%= text_field_tag :timeMax, params[:timeMax] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search Near", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

How would I do this? 'date' saves the datetime for each event

I would like the user to be able to search by: time, location, time and location, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using scopes? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope

Comment: yes, but I would like to use the built in geocoder search. It's really effective, but I need to be able to add other functionality to it

Comment: Have you considered other search plugins that might be easier to implement like: http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch?view=asciicast